# How to run ruby on rails application in RubyMine IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

In python/flask, file `app.py` can be called from an IDE or the console to run an entire web application.

In Ruby on Rails, I use `bin/rails server` in the console to start a server to run the rails app, but I am having a hard time doing the same in RubyMine IDE. I tried running `application_controller.rb` file, but nothing happened.

Which file should I run in IDE to start the server and see the web app in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a Rails server from the reference [Ruby Mine Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/running-rails-server.html)

1. Press `Shift+Alt+F10`, and choose the desired Rails run/debug
   configuration type.
2. If necessary, change the run/debug configuration settings. To do
   that, choose Edit configurations... in the Run popup menu, and
   choose the desired Rails configuration type. Rails run/debug
   configuration dialog box appears.
3. In this dialog box, modify the desired settings. For example,
   RubyMine suggests WEBrick as the default Rails server. You can
   select a different server from the list of supported servers.
4. Click the I> button on the main toolbar.

Comment: In Mac the key comb is "⌃⌥R". I just used to pick application_controller instead of development.